# Remember all opened files with split windows and their positions in Emacs

Tags: emacs

It took really a lot of time to get used to Emacs, but everything I want to have from normal editor like [Coda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_%28web_development_software%29), is just impossible without additional scripts.

**I want to restore everything like it was before.**

Split windows, their position, opened files/shells/debugger. Everything back to as it was. Coda can do this, [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) can do this, anything can do this.

When I need any normal feature for Emacs it always needs tons of scripts to have it. I thought I really would die with pyflakes, code-color, shrink-windows bindings and 20 other scripts which I even don't remember... Why are so many elementary things not integrated already???

Any good books for beginners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found *[Conveniently save and restore frame configurations](https://tsdh.wordpress.com/2006/11/26/conveniently-save-and-restore-frame-configuration/)*, and it might be doing what you are looking for.

Comment: finally something useful, thnx for this link! =)It's strange that emacs supports tabs but couldn't keep their configuration when opening editor again..

Comment: I looked into it more, and it doesn't work cross-sessions (aka emacs restarts). Instead you can use revive.el from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowsMode . I was able to use it last night to save window split configurations and restore them later, even after a restart. Now what I am not clear on is that it seems to not always restore the actual content of the buffer. Specifically it doesn't always work with nav mode buffers (code.google.com/p/emacs-nav/, ide-like file explorer). Maybe I need to dig more on http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement

Answer (score 9):

Take a look under "Options" > "Customize Emacs".

It sounds like you want to enable two features:

- "Save Place" which saves the location in each file the next time you load it.
- "Desktop" which saves all the files you currently have loaded.

Or if you feel like editing your .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
  '(desktop-enable t nil (desktop))
  '(save-place t nil (saveplace)))
```

Comment: will this save splited windows also? I have 3 windows usually, in one it's shell in other two, 2 files opened. will this save a position of windows also? btw im using emacs in shell,

Comment: I don't believe it saves the splits or split locations (doesn't in my version). Not sure if you mean splitting the visible frame into 3 buffers or launching 3 frames; but either way AFAIK it only reloads the files you had open when you exited and remembers your edit location in each. So you would have to resplit and change each buffer to your desired file. You'll have to relaunch the shell from w/in emacs.

Comment: in fact question was: can i save buffer split positions?? can I make a config or something like that ? (everytime I enter to emacs, i want to see my splited buffer with my width and height which were set before)

Comment: to save place in `.emacs` (emacs 23): `(require 'saveplace) (setq-default save-place t)`

Answer (score 5):

I have this working. Emacs always starts back up exactly as I left it, unless it crashes...:

http://www.gentei.org/~yuuji/software/windows.el

This will save all window spits and open buffers:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SavePlace

Thise will save your place in files. Here roughly how to set it up:

```
(require 'windows)
(require 'recentf)

;; -- Load the saved windows automatically on boot
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'resume-windows)

;; -- Save place in file
(setq-default save-place t)

;; --  Use this command to quit and save your setup
(define-key ctl-x-map "C" 'see-you-again)

;; -- Set up window saving!! Place at end of .emacs file
(win:startup-with-window)
```

Comment: works perfectly. I set it up on emacs-live, in my personal pack. Had to also load revive.el prior to windows.el.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowsMode

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it is nearing to what you want, but give it a try: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LayoutRestore

Comment: No it's not. After quitting emacs, after I wake up in the morning, I want to continue with the same layout as it was before. Same splits, same files opened in  them, same width/heigh of the splits..everything THE SAME as it was before quiting emacs.. Every editor has things like that. I hate VIM but in vim you can restore everything back as it was...

Answer (score 1):

Emacs 24.4 snapshots [since June 2013](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/revision/113242) have added frame restoration to the bundled session manager desktop.el.  This includes restoring desktop position and opened windows of all frames.  I have tried this feature myself using a January 2014 snapshot and it works pretty well, though a few minor bugs remain.  These may have already been fixed in more recent snapshots.

Note that some buffers cannot easily be restored even in theory, such as debuggers (gdb, pdb, etc.) and any others buffer that depends on an external process.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and is nicely documented here: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_save_restore_opened_files.html