# Open windows and load specific buffers in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp

I'm working on my .emacs configuration for clojure development.

What I want to happen is whenever I open a file called "project.clj" if there is no open buffer called "*swank*", split the window first horizontally then split the right side vertically.  Then from the project.clj buffer run (clojure-jack-in) to start the REPL and (shell) to load a bash shell.  When all of this is done I'd like the project.clj file to be in the left window, the shell to be in the top right window, and the REPL to be in the bottom right window.

Also if there's a way to get speedbar to open in a specified window rather than in a new frame, that would be awesome.

I guess my question is: is there a way to specify which window new buffers are opened in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, how about [this answer via ibuffer](https://superuser.com/a/305494/147087) or via [grid-files-sq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441270/1404208) or [GridLayout](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GridLayout) and (more unrelatedly) [desktop remembering suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792449/emacs-remember-all-opened-files-with-splitted-windows-and-their-positions)